# Need to write Linq to SQL identity value to another field in same table

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

ASP.NET 4.0 C#, Linq to SQL: I have a requirement that once a new row is created I need to write the identity value back to another field in the same row.

I tried this but it didn't work (row not found or changed):

```
//newRow created and fields populated here
dc.Table.InsertOnSubmit(newRow);
dc.SubmitChanges();
newRow.Field = newRow.PriKey;
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

I also tried reading the row into a new variable and updating but same error:

```
//newRow created and fields populated here
dc.Table.InsertOnSubmit(newRow);
dc.SubmitChanges();
row2 = (from r in dc.Table where r.PriKey = newRow.PriKey select r).FirstOrDefault();
row2.Field = newRow.PriKey;
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

I guess I can do this easily by creating and executing my own SQL command but is there an easier way to do it?

Edit: Does the fact that this wrapped in a transaction make a difference?

```
using (CMSDataContext dc = new CMSDataContext(Config.ConnString))
{
    dc.Connection.Open();
    dc.Transaction = dc.Connection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
```

Comment: just for fun have you tried assigning `newRow.PriKey` to a local variable (say int, short, etc) and then `newRow.Field = localvariable`

Comment: peroija: yes, I tried this but it did not help. In the end I gave up on fixing this problem properly and just ran a query to fix the data as it was something I only needed to do one time.

Answer (score 1):

This not seem to be a limitation of LINQ2SQL, running the below in LINQPad seems to work fine.  Have you tried stepping through your code in the debugger? Or can you post your real code to check for other issues?

```
create table data
(
    ID int not null identity primary key,
    Value varchar(16) not null,
    PKStore int null
)

var newRow = new Data{Value = "MyVal"};
Data.InsertOnSubmit(newRow);
SubmitChanges();

newRow.PKStore = newRow.ID;
SubmitChanges();

Data.Dump(); //LINQPad Method
```

Outputs

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try order by and selecting the top row from the list

```
dc.Table.InsertOnSubmit(newRow);
dc.SubmitChanges();
row2 = (from r in dc.Table  order by r.PriKey desecnding select r).FirstOrDefault();
row2.Field = row2.PriKey;
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: i wouldn't suggest doing this at all. if you have two people adding `newRow` at the same you may end up getting the wrong value

Comment: the question asks about update read the question before making comment

Comment: my comment is directed at your 3rd line `row2 = (from r in dc.Table  order by r.PriKey desecnding select r).FirstOrDefault();` In this line you are grabbing whatever value happens to show first, regardless of whether or not it came from the newRow just submitted. the OP asked for the PK value from the newly created row to be entered back into the same row and your response won't always do that.

Comment: the event of submitting happens before I select the row the row on my example is sorted in the descending order based on the prikey which is an identity based on question identity always increases by one which means it would be a top row and the highest number of identity or the one just created

Comment: which leads to my first comment of two people adding rows at the same time. if your write goes in, then my write, you would select my prikey because it is the higher number.

Comment: again I will repeat upper action usually happens before the bottom action

Comment: this has drawn out too far, i stand by my statement that your code allows for the situation that i described. whether the chance of it happening is small or large it is never appropriate to allow for the chance to occur. this destroys the integrity of the code and the data